# wrapping a UIButton in UIBarButtonItem selector doesn't invoke

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I created the following class to get a toolbar with colored images

```
@interface likeUIBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem
- (id) initWithStatus: (enum ApartmentLikeStatus)p_status;
@end
```

and the m file looks like this:

```
- (IBAction) likeStatus_Clicked: (id) sender
{
    self.numberOfClicks++;
    [self.statusButton setImage:[self getStatusImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (id) initWithStatus: (enum ApartmentLikeStatus)p_status
{
    self.statusButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.statusButton setImage:[self getStatusImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.statusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeStatus_Clicked:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.statusButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    self = [[likeUIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.statusButton];

    return self;
}
```

in the view controller I do the following:

```
likeUIBarButtonItem* stausBtn = [[likeUIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithStatus:self.apartmentToShow.userLikness];
// List of toolbaritems
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: stausBtn, nil];
self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

the button gets displayed but when clicking it i get an assembly code

```
0x120a09f:  movl   (%edi), %esi  <-- thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 address=0x0)
```

although my statusButton is declared `(strong, nonatomic)` my guess it gets released somewhere between the init and the call to the function, is that the case or is it something else? and whatever it is how do I fix it?

Comment: Objective-C best practices: you should start your class names with capital letters (e.g. "'LikeUIBarButtonItem'") while variable names should be what starts with lower case letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you override an `init*` method.

You might be better off with something like this

```
- (instancetype)initWithStatus:(enum ApartmentLikeStatus)status
{
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button setImage:[self getStatusImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(likeStatus_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];

  self = [super initWithCustomView:button];
  if (self) {
    self.statusButton = button;
  }
  return self;
}
```

The problem with your version is that you create a button and assign it to `self` but then you reassign `self` to a completely new object at the end. So the initial `self` probably be released immediately as no one else can get a handle on it, which basically means you are passing a dangling pointer into the `initWithCustomView:` method